# How to add "version" query strings to the URLs of the static resources of a web-page?

Tags: php, javascript, css, apache, caching

I've noticed that Stack Overflow adds `?v=xxxxxxxxxxxx`:

[image]

to the scripts and style sheets that are bound to the web-page. This, in conjunction with the `Cache-Control` response header

```
Cache-Control   max-age=604800
```

which is being sent for those static resources, makes sure that the same script or style sheet is cached (in the browser) for one week.

I would like to use this technique. Could you tell me how that query string is added to the URLs? My source code looks like so:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I assume that the value of `v` is determined by the Last-Modified value of the file. Does that mean that for **every** request to my `.php` web-page, I have to access the last-modified information for **every** static resource? (I feel that would be a performance hit.)

Comment: Note that query strings are not the best solution for versioning static assets. A solution involving hashes of the file, in the filename, is better since they change only when bytes of the file are changed. Also, some (older?) browsers omit query strings when searching their caches. I recommend `grunt-hashres`. Another starting point at http://www.theasta.net/talks/2013-05-22/#/, or google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, for ease, I append the `filemtime()` as a GET param. Some people append a number from version control, such as a revision number.

Comment: I'm concerned about performance. Calling `filemtime()` for each static resource for each page request is OK?

Comment: However the GET parameter is calculated (I think `filetime()` is a good idea), it is (most often) statically included in the HTML, so no performance hit.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas As the old saying goes, profile it and see if it is the bottleneck of your application. It has never caused me a concern on any of my sites. You may want to use a different metric if it's a concern.

Comment: @alex How does `filemtime()` compare to reading from the database (performance-wise)? I could have a "Static resources" table in the database with version-information. I would then manually run a script to update that table (whenever I change a static resource), and the PHP pages would retrieve the `v` values from that table.

Answer (score 2):

Different (versions of) page templates will need different versions of the .js and .css - so you can statically embed the dependent versions string into the page tempalte.

Comment: I'm not sure what a page template is (in this context), but I have a `article.php` page which generates different articles based on the ID (e.g. `article.php?id=007`). How do I statically embed?

Comment: I am quite positive your `article.php` will not echo all the HTML from hardcoded values, but either have some static HTML directly in the `article.php` file (what some people, including me, consider bad style), or include some static HTML either directly or via a template parsing engine. This static parts of the HTML rendering are teh page template I mean.

Comment: Well, yes. My `.php` file is pretty much HTML code. There are only a couple of `<?php ... ?>` blocks. (Wait, is that bad style?) I don't know how to "statically embed the dependent versions string". Could you explain?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Somwhere in your HTML there will be something like `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`, which you can replace with `<script src="js/script.js?v=XXXXXXX"></script>` with the version XXXXXXX being the one, that fits this HTML. Once you change (and test, blah blah nada nada) a new version of either JS or HTML adapt the XXXXXXX

Comment: Well, yes, that would work, but that would also mean that I would have to manually edit the PHP page whenever I change any of the static resources bound to it. That just doesn't seem like a reasonable idea.

Comment: You have the choice between creating it automatically (this includes a performance hit) or creating it manually on deployment of a new version (this includes a labour hit) - you can't eat your cake and have it.

Comment: I assumed that it's clear that I want to have it done dynamically. My question is how. (I'm a PHP noob and I'm asking for solutions.) `filemtime()` is one solution but there may be a better (better-performing) solution...